# remote connection through wmi is not working properly with multithreading

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, wmi

I'm trying to connect to a remote windows machine using the wmi module. I'm using the logic based on code in this link - http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577945-execute-remote-commands-on-windows-like-psexec/

When I'm running this code in isolation and try to connect to a machine I'm able to connect,however, when I'm running the code in the multithreading environment I'm getting  the following error for one of the case but the in the other thread I'm able to connect successfully.

This is the error -

```
2013-11-26 17:26:47,270::Thread-5::6544::Could not connect to machine - <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567,
'Exception occurred.', (0, u'SWbemLocator',
u'Access is denied. ', None, 0, -2147024891), None)>
```

This is my code

```
class ConnectMsToMs():
    '''    This class provide the functionality to transfer 
           file b/w windows OS. One can also delete/execute 
           any file on remote computer. '''

    def __init__(self, log, ip,
                 username, password,remote_path=r'c:\\test_script'):
        self.log = log
        self.ip = str(ip)
        self.username = str(username)
        self.password = str(password)
        self.remote_path = remote_path

        try:
            pythoncom.CoInitialize()
            self.log.thread_log("Establishing connection to %s" % self.ip)
            self.connection = wmi.WMI(self.ip, user=self.username,
                                      password=self.password)
            self.log.thread_log("Connection established")
        #except wmi.x_wmi:
        except Exception,err:
            self.log.thread_log("Could not connect to machine - %s"%str(err))
            raise
```

This is the structure in which my connect to ConnectMsToMs object is called.

main() - > DTC{inherit threading which call run.} - > dba.sanity(){ this is a function of different class, this fn intern call connnect} -> connect() { this fn create the object of my ConnectMsToMs and try to connect to system}

Answer (score 0):

Im running into the same issue and so far have not found any information on how to resolve the solution.

I have successfully connected to the machine using the windows program 'Remote Desktop' so I know the service is active and accepting connections from this machine.

I am trying to test with the following line

```
connection = wmi.WMI("192.168.1.5", user="username", password="password")
```

Which results in

```
x_access_denied: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'SWbemLocator', u'Access is denied. ', None, 0, -2147024891), None)>
```